# getting no result with dynamic drop list

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

[image]I have attached the code to get dynamic drop list from DB. when user choose from the first drop list using onChange() the data of second drop list will be retrieved depending on selection of first drop list. However, I can get the first drop list but no result for second drop list. It seem the ajax does not called.

ANOTHER QUESTION:

Can I make radio button for second drop list instead

Thank you

```js
<?php

echo"1"
if(isset($_POST['get_option']))
{
 $host = 'localhost';
 $user = 'root';
 $pass = 'root';
 mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
 mysql_select_db('db_photography');
 $state = $_POST['get_option'];
 $find=mysql_query("select city from places where state='$state'");
 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($find))
 {
  echo"1";
  echo "<option>".$row['city']."</option>";
 }
 exit;
}
?>
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="select_style.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function fetch_select(val)
{
 $.ajax({
 type: 'post',
 url: 'fetch_data.php',
 data: {
  get_option:val
 },
 success: function (response) {
  document.getElementById("new_select").innerHTML=response; 
 }
 });
}

</script>

</head>
<body>
<p id="heading">Dynamic Select Option Menu Using Ajax and PHP</p>
<center>
<div id="select_box">
 <select onchange="fetch_select(this.value);">
  <option>Select state</option>
  <?php
  $host = 'localhost';
  $user = 'root';
  $pass = 'root';
  mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
  mysql_select_db('db_photography');

  $select=mysql_query("select state from places group by state");
  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($select))
  {
   echo "<option>".$row['state']."</option>";
  }
 ?>
 </select>

 <select id="new_select">
 </select>
   
</div>     
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does `response` looks like? Because `new_select` is a select option element, you may append it with `option` tags.

Comment: empty result. the drop list does not open. you can see pic

Comment: Is the function called? Try in your query `"select city from places where state='.$state.'"`

Comment: it seems to me the whole file does not execute. I tried to echo"1"; but it does not execute

Comment: Maybe the location of your PHP file

Comment: they are in same folder. is the Ajax code correct. I am new with it